# The timing to delete QObject using QObject::deleteLater()

Tags: qt, qobject

Sample:

```
Test::Test(QWidget *parent)
{
    qDebug() <<"Test()";
}

Test::~Test()
{
    qDebug() <<"~Test()";
}

void MainWindow::slot_test()
{
    Test *p = new Test;
    // out Test() message here ok

    p->deleteLater();

    QCoreApplication::sendPostedEvents(0, 0);
    QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents);

    // no ~Test() message out here
    ....
}
```

I know that the implement of deleteLater is call
QCoreApplication::postEvent(this, new QDeferredDeleteEvent());

But why no "~Test()" message out when run after QCoreApplication::sendPostedEvents(0, 0) or run after QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents) ?

The above tow codes should dispatche all events in event queue, including QEvent::DeferredDelete?

The "~Test()" message appears when leave the function slot_test().

I think I don't understand the true meaning "The object will be deleted when control returns to the event loop"  in the qt's document.

Could someone explain more clearly?

Comment: It is possible that the delete happens on the next event loop cycle, giving queued events the chance to get processed before deleting the referenced object. In this context, forcing the processing of events in the current cycle should not trigger the deletion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation for [`QCoreApplication::processEvents`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents)...

> In the event that you are running a local loop which calls this
>   function continuously, without an event loop, **the DeferredDelete
>   events will not be processed** [My emphasis].

If you change...

```
QCoreApplication::sendPostedEvents(0, 0);
QCoreApplication::processEvents(QEventLoop::AllEvents);
```

to...

```
QCoreApplication::instance()->exec();
```

Then you should get the expected behaviour.

(**Note:** I know that blocking your `MainWindow::slot_test` with a call to `QCoreApplication::exec` isn't a long term solution but... I'm guessing from its name -- `slot_test` -- that this is a `Qt` `slot` and will be invoked within the context of the main event loop anyway.  In which case `slot_test` will return to that event loop and the DeferredDelete event processed there.)